# how to fix protocol violation in c#

Tags: c#, java, wcf

I have a c# "client" and a Java "server".  The java server has a wsdl it serves to the client.
So far it works for c# to make a request for the server to perform a soap action. My server gets the soap request  executes the method and tries to return the result back to the client.

When I send the response to c# however, I get "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine".

I have spent all day trying to fix this and have come up with nothing that works. If I explain what i did, this post would be very long, so I'll keep it brief.

i Googled for hours and everything tells me my "response line" is correct. I tried shutting down Skype, rearranging the response line, adding things, taking things away, etc, etc. All to no avail.

This is for a class assignment so no, I can not use apis to help. I must do everything manually on the server side. That means parsing by hand, creating the soap response and the http response by hand. Just thought you'd like to know that before you say to use something that does it for me.

I even tried making sure my server was sending the correct header by creating a java client that "mimicked" the c# one so I could see what the server returned. However, it's returning exactly what i told it to send.

I tried telling my java client to do the same thing but to an actuall running c# service, to see what a real service returns, and it returned basically the same thing. To be safe, I copied it's response and tried sending it to the c# client and it still threw the error.

Can anyone help? I've tried all i can think of, including adding the useUnsafeHeaderParsing to my app config. Nothing is working though. I send it exactly what a real service sends it and it yells at me. I send it what i want and it yells.

I'm sending this:

```
"200 OK HTTP/1.0\r\n" +
"Content-Length: 201\r\n" +
"Cache-Control: private\r\n" +
"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Vote to close - Homework questions are explicitly not really something supported here.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for your error is that you've got the status line syntax wrong.  According to the RFC, the status line syntax is:

> Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF

You got the parts of the response status line around the wrong way ... like the error message is telling you!

---

Some advice:

- Don't try to talk HTTP or SOAP at this level.  These protocols are complicated, and there are existing well-implemented, well-document libraries that do this kind of thing.  Use them and don't waste your time reinventing the wheel.
- If you really do want / need to implement this stuff yourself, it is CRITICAL that you read and understand the relevant specifications.  They are easy to find using Google.

(I'm not going to provide links <s>because that would only encourage you to waste your time on building the software equivalent of horse carts with square wheels.</s> because you need to learn to find and use them yourself ... as a matter of course.)

Comment: OP: "This is for a class assignment so no, I can not use apis to help. I must do everything manually..."

Comment: @TimS - so the OP needs to find the specification and read it in order to do his homework.  I would consider finding the specification to be part of the homework.  (And besides, he / she should be told that this is NOT the way to write REAL applications.)

Comment: I had that way before but it causes another problem(one fixed by switching the ways. Well kinda fixed).

If I have this:

    "HTTP/1.1 100 100-continue\r\n\r\n";
It will send it but c# wont send the body. I got around that by switching the order and then c# sends the body. So how do I use the proper form AND still have c# send me the body? If I close the output stream it will cause an error, but c# wont send the body even after i asked for it.

Comment: @JeremyStyers - Read the specification.  Read the specification.  Randomly changing things to make them work is Voodoo programming.